# bittorrent piece selection stradegy

Tags: bittorrent

I have a question regarding the piece selecion stradegy. It is mentioned in a paper that there is a "Strick Priority" as below:

> BitTorrent’s first policy for piece selection is that
>   once a single sub-piece has been requested, the remaining sub-pieces from that particular piece are requested before sub-pieces from any other piece. This
>   does a good job of getting complete pieces as quickly
>   as possible.

The stradegy above is easy to understand, but it does not mention from the peer's point of view.

So here is my question:

1. Is it true that all the blocks for a piece should be requested from the same peer?
2. If answer of question 1 is true, does the client will request the same block from diffrent peers at the same time in case some peer failed to respond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it true that all the blocks for a piece should be requested from the same peer?

False. The idea is, by requesting different blocks from different peers, adding together the bandwidth from all the peers to complete the piece quickly.

> does the client will request the same block from diffrent peers at the same time in case some peer failed to respond?

Normally a specific block is only requested from one peer. Only if that peer hasn't sent that block after a long time out, that block is requested from another peer.

A exception from this is the "End Game" mode.
When the download is almost complete and all remaining blocks has been requested:
Blocks may be requested in parallel from more than one peer to avoid needing to wait for the slowest peers to finish their blocks and make the download slow down to a crawl.